# pause JW player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, video, jwplayer

I have three tabs.

Each tab having two videos in slider.
The problem is when I switch any tab **or** click any single video,all other should pause.

I can collect all the ids and then loop over to use stop().But is there any other method that is much more cleaner and simpler.?

```
jwplayer('video_pub').stop(); //for 1 video..how can i do for all videos?
```

Comment: Use pause instead of stop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `jwplayer().stop()`, you can use `jwplayer().pause()`

for this, I mostly prefer `jwplayer().play(false).`

Source : [Jwplayer API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/)

**LOGIC**

> just get the parent video wrapper which have all tab (since
>   each tab has two video)... find jwplayer whiich is currently being
>   played and stop all other players.

```
pauseMedia : function(playingMediaId) {
        $('#parent_video_wrapper').find('.jwplayer, object').each(function(){
            currentMediaId =$(this).attr('id');
            if( jwplayer(this).getState() == "PLAYING" || jwplayer(this).getState() == "BUFFERING" ) {
                if(currentMediaId != playingMediaId){
                    jwplayer(this).play(false);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

> now you can either use above function as pauseMedia() or
>   pauseMedia(mediaId), Both will work

In video Setup if you use it like this

```
jwplayer("video_"+videoId).setup({

events : {
onPlay : function (callback){
        var playingVideoId = 'video_'+videoId;
        pauseMedia(playingVideoId); 
       //pausing other simulatenously playing video in a tab

}
}
});
```

I think above code might do the trick, just give it a try

Comment: I want this on click of tab...is it possible that way?i mean can i call the function pause_media on click of my tab..and i dont know how to use onPlay and what that does..

Comment: onPlay() event is triggered when video is being played ... it can be defined in setup in event as I have used or you can use it outside of setup jwplayer().onPlay( function(event){
    alert('video is playing');
}); .....  http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28850/using-the-javascript-api/