# Stopping JWplayer players before loading new player

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am having trouble stopping all existing/running players before loading new a player.  Only one player should be running at once.

My site is loads a z-layer with the player in.  The problem is that if I click the playlist links more than once, it loads multiple players, and even continues playing when the z-layer is closed.

All calls to the player use the same id:  player1

I have looked at these references:

- http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062894-stop-all-players-with-javascript
- http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/5496339-jwplayer-stop-how-to-use-this-code-for-multiple-players-

I have tried calling:

```
jwplayer("player1").stop()
```

before:

```
jwplayer("player1").setup({
```

and also:

```
onclick="jwplayer(\'player1\').stop();"
```

inside the playlist `<a href ...>` links

but neither work. What is wrong please?

Also there is a white 'flash' on loading now which was not there before I tried these stopping methods.  I have tried to change the background colour for var D="#000000", as described here:

but 'var D' is not in the jwplayer.js file.

Comment: Where is this running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pause JW player?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091761/pause-jw-player)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091761/pause-jw-player

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `jwplayer().stop()`, In case if you just want player to pause when other jwplayer is working , you can use `jwplayer().pause()`

for this, I mostly prefer `jwplayer().play(false).` but if you are trying to remove the player `jwplayer().remove()` will do the trick.

Source : [Jwplayer API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/)

for more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22093493/1877909) for similar type of question

Comment: You have copy-pasted the *exact* answer from the other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091761/pause-jw-player/22093493#22093493 . Omg :o

Comment: But Its my own answer and I have answered in both place. Do I still have to delete it ?

Comment: Updated my answer. By the way It is my own answer, I have not copied it. Kindly check the name of the person in both answer.@Aleks

Comment: @halfer : If you have other answer which is relevant to the question please add. I would also like to other ways to stop the player before loading new player. Thanks !!!

Comment: "I have answered in both place", yes, we discourage that. If the same answer can be provided to two questions then it is likely they are duplicates of each other, and looking at them now they indeed do seem very similar indeed, so I have cast a close vote. As far as I know, you have enough reputation to cast a close vote - do that instead please.

Comment: @halfer : on second thought, Both question does seems same. Thanks for correction. I have also given close vote for this question